# Show that $E_n$ has empty interior

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have an exercise I am not sure how to solve:

Let $L_1([0,1], m)$ be the Lebesgue space on $[0,1]$.
We have that $L_3([0,1], m)\not \subseteq L_1([0,1], m)$.
For $n \geq 1$, define $E_n:=\{f\in L_1([0,1], m): \int_{[0,1]} |f|^3 \ dm \leq n\}$

Show that $E_n$ has empty interior in $L_1([0,1], m)$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I am thinking that I first have to show that the $L_1([0,1]$ has empty interior and then conclude that $E_ n$ empty interior. But I am not sure how to do that. Someone who can help?

Comment: Who told you $L_3([0,1], m)\not \subseteq L_1([0,1], m)$ ? That's not true, in fact $L_3([0,1], m)\subseteq L_1([0,1], m)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $f\in E_n$ the sequence $\frac 1 {n\sqrt x}+f$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}$ but no term of this sequence is in $E_n$.